# creating lined up text with string in C# from access database

Tags: c#, string, ms-access, text

i'm using C# to read info from an access database (works great, thx stackoverflow)
i'm trying to make a lined up text string so i can display it in textbox and later on print it as a string, not the best way, but it should work (if you think of a better option tell me)

```
public string ItemToString(int item_id)
        {
           string[] userString = new string[7];
           string retString=""; 
           cmd.CommandText = "select * from Item where item_id = " + item_id + "";

           con.Open(); // open the connection
           OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           while (dr.Read())
           {
               for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                   userString[i] = dr[i].ToString();
           }
            con.Close();
            //string conection with spaces
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                retString += userString[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < 15-userString[i].Length; j++, retString += "  ") ;
            }
            return retString;
        }
```

this is the output (in hebrew) the first line is from other place, mind only lines 2-4 i added the red line to see where it's "off"
[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using non-proportional font (like courier), pad with spaces using any possible way. Get familiar with `ToString()` function and formats for padding, to make it easy.

If you're printing or displaying as graphics or proportional font, get familiar with `Graphics.MeasureString`. It lets you measure how many pixels the string will take, using given font and size. Then you can draw it in correct place. Measure the whole string and not single letters, if you don't want to make it really complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the font of the textbox to be a non-proportional font (like courier).

Comment: it works, but is there some other way? the font solution is good but the font isn't the best for my final print (i know, but if there is other way...)

Comment: You want the start of each column to line up vertically?  Unless you change from a `TextBox` to a grid-based control, I don't see how you can do that without using a fixed-width font.  At least, not easily.  You'd have to be able to measure the width in pixels of each character and then pad with as many spaces as needed to get close to that pixel width.

Comment: found another way String.Format